# Why does Files.createSymbolicLink() throw java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException for link parameter?

Tags: java, linux, java-8

I am trying to create a symbolic link on a Linux machine using Java.

I am using java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink. The first parameter is a Path `link`, and the second parameter is a Path `target`.

I have verified that the `target` Path exists, and that the `link` Path does not exist but is the symbolic link that I want created.

Why do I keep getting `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: <link path>` when the code is run? I cannot find in documentation why I would get a NoSuchFileException for the `link` path. I would understand getting the error for the `target` path, but the `target` path definitely exists.

```
public static Path createSymbolicLink(Path link,
                                      Path target,
                                      FileAttribute<?>... attrs)
                               throws IOException
```

I tried tried swapping `target` and `link` parameters and it worked, but the symlink is backwards. I need a symlink in /var/foo to /data/bar but instead I got a symlink from /data/bar to /var/foo.

The parent directories of `link` all exist.

I tried digging through the actual OpenJDK Java code to see why a NoSuchFileException is being thrown, but it is not clear.

My only guess is it is something to do with the fact that I am trying to create a symbolic link to a directory, not a file. I will tinker with trailing file slashes to see if that helps.

Comment: Does the directory exist that you are trying to create the link inside?

Comment: What do you mean with “but the symlink is backwards”? The direction always is from the to-be-created link pointing to the already-existing file. How could it be otherwise?

Comment: The only way I could provoke a `NoSuchFileException` is when the directory where the link should be created doesn't exist (i.e. if I want to create a link `somedir/somelink` but `somedir` doesn't exist)

Comment: @ThomasKläger That is useful information to have. In my case, it ended up being a similar issue where, even though the symlink path existed, the application simply did not have read/write access to the filesystem containing the path for the symlink.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the docs it seems the `target` is the one that may or may not exist yet and the `link` attribute is the one that must indeed exist, not the other way around, as your question seems to suggest.

Comment: The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) clearly states the `createSymbolicLink()` creates a link to the target and describes the parameters as "link - the path of the symbolic link to create" and "target - the target of the symbolic link", so your assumption is wrong. Please note that to create a symbolic link the target doesn't need to exist

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the issue.

If you get a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException which complains about the `link` path and not the `target` path, make sure your application can write to the `link` path.

In my case, the `link` path was valid and the `target` path was valid, but my application could not access the `link` path for writing so an unclear java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException was thrown.

As @ThomasKläger noted, you may also receive a NoSuchFileException if a parent directory of the symlink path does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is also thrown when the target is an empty path.
For example, with the following:

```java
    Path l=Paths.get("mylink"), t=Paths.get("");
    Files.createSymbolicLink(l, t);
```

Output:

```
Exception java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: mylink
      at UnixException.translateToIOException (UnixException.java:92)
      at UnixException.rethrowAsIOException (UnixException.java:106)
      at UnixException.rethrowAsIOException (UnixException.java:111)
      at UnixFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink (UnixFileSystemProvider.java:471)
      at Files.createSymbolicLink (Files.java:1069)
      at (#40:1)
```

I guess the reason for only the link showing up is that the implementation simply calls `UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(link)` instead of the alternative with two UnixPath arguments, `UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(link, target)`.

The latter would end up as a new [FileSystemException(file, other)](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/nio/file/FileSystemException.java#L72)